# from time import timestart_time = time() , outputs syntax error

Tags: python, time, import

from time, importing time_start = time () gives me a syntax error.

i tried just importing start_time () assuming that 'time' is just part of the standard library.

```
from time import timestart_time = time() 

from random import randint 

requests = 0

for _ in range(5):
      requests += 1 
      sleep(radiant(1,3))
      elapsed_time = time() - start_time 
      print ('request: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests/elapsed_time))
```

Ii expect the library to import with no error, i am probably over thinking the issue, thank you.

Comment: Please do not post more code than is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's because you're doing it incorrectly.  [The import Statement](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/#the-import-statement)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I think I'm doing the same tutorial.  There's tonnes of bits missing that you have to work out.

Answer (score 3):

It's:

```
from time import time
start_time = time()
```

Add a newline after the `import` statement, or worse, a semicolon:

```
from time import time;start_time = time()
```